# When clicking on icon in a li how do I determine if its the first li in the ul?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a ul and each li inside it has a trash icon and when I press the trash I want to know if its the first icon in the ul. What I'm trying always returns false. I also tried

```
$(this).parents('li').is(':first');
```

with no luck

```js
$("ul#sortable").on("click", ".removethumb", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
   
    $isThumbPrimary = $(this).is(':first');
    
});
```

```html
<ul id="sortable" style="list-style-type: none; padding-left: 0px;">
  @foreach (var image in Model.ViewImages.OrderBy(i => i.Ordering)) {
  <li id="@image.YogaSpaceImageId" class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 imagethumbs" data-yogaspaceid="@Model.YogaSpaceId">

    <div class="thumbnail" style="background-color: lightgrey;">
      <a id="@image.YogaSpaceImageId" class="close removethumb" href="#" style="padding-top: 2px; position: absolute; z-index: 3000;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true" style="padding: 5px;"></span></a>
      @{ var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(image.ImageThumbnail); var thumbSrc = String.Format("data:image/gif;base64,{0}", base64); var base64Modal = Convert.ToBase64String(image.Image); var imgSrcModal = String.Format("data:image/gif;base64,{0}", base64Modal);
      var imageId = "pop" + image.YogaSpaceImageId; var imagesourceId = "imagesource" + image.YogaSpaceImageId; } @*
      <a class="image" id="@imageId" href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
        <img id="@imagesourceId" src="@thumbSrc" data-imagesrc="@imgSrcModal" alt="image not found" width="203" height="136" />
      </a>*@
      <a class="image" id="@imageId" href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; position: relative;">
        <img id="@imagesourceId" src="@thumbSrc" data-imagesrc="@imgSrcModal" alt="image not found" style="width: 100%; height: 100%" @*width="203" height="136" *@ />
      </a>
    </div>



  </li>
  }
</ul>
```

Comment: if your code was not wrapped in $(document).ready(); then i think the problem is with the position of your script tags. you should put it after the body tag. and your code should work

Answer (score 2):

`:first` should be `:first-child`

```js
$("ul#sortable").on("click", ".removethumb", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  //$isThumbPrimary = $(this).is(':first');
  alert($(this).is(':first-child'))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="sortable">
  <li class="removethumb">one</li>
  <li class="removethumb">two</li>
  <li class="removethumb">three</li>
</ul>
```

Given the nesting of your elements I think you actually need `$(this).closest('li').is(':first-child')`

```js
$("ul#sortable").on("click", ".removethumb", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();

  alert($(this).closest('li').is(':first-child'))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="sortable">
  <li class="removethumb">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <a class="removethumb" href="#">one</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="removethumb">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <a class="removethumb" href="#">two</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="removethumb">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <a class="removethumb" href="#">three</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```